# Server Control Render inside Server Control

Tags: c#, servercontrols

I have 2 server control

One create Items
the other one create a List of items.

So i have a public Item with a viewstate in the first 
in the page when i add the server control name (Server control name 1) to a panel it render (with a `createChildControls`) and add to a public `List<Server Name 1>` that is a view state in the server control 2.

so i make

```
foreach  (ServerControl_1 a in ServerControl_2)

output += a;
```

the result is the namespace of the item not the text.

So i must have to render it first and then add to the output...
But i just dont know how...

Someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

use something like

```
        protected String displayName(Object item)
        {
            String name = "";
            if (item != null && item.hasOwnProperty("name")) {
                name = item["name"];
            }
            return name;
        }
```

call this in your for loop.

```
output += displayName(a)
```

Comment: sure it is, you want the "name" or "text" property of your Object and not "ServerControl_1 object" to appear in your ddl list